# I can not build or run my static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I do not know what happened to my project. I can not select iOS simulator or iOS device to build my static library. Just like the picture below

[image]

Comment: I use Xcode 7.0.1, and I  have used  `git  status` to check my code of my project. nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I closed Xcode, and open the *.xcodeproj file, delete xcuserdata folder, open my project again. Everything is ok now.